# Accessing object values from an ObservableArray and displaying them in a Label

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm having trouble accessing the values of objects stored in an ObservableArray:

```
const observable = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
const ObservableArray = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

var myArray = new ObservableArray([]);

var pageData = observable.fromObject({
    myArray: myArray
});

exports.onLoad = function (args) {
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
    // a Bluetooth plugin returns a peripheral object
    myArray.push(peripheral);
    //console.log(Object.keys(peripheral));
}
```

The `console.log()` function prints the `peripheral` object like this:

```
JS: [type, UUID, name, RSSI, state, advertisement, manufacturerId, manufacturerData]
```

This is my XML file:

```
<Page loaded="onLoad">
    <ListView items="{{ myArray }}">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label text="{{ peripheral['UUID'] }}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

The ListView items are loading just fine, but I can't get the Label to show any value of the peripheral object. I'm pretty sure the `peripheral['UUID']` syntax is wrong but I can't find information on how to access this data...

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`peripheral` was just your variable name that does not exists in the array. Simply bind the `UUID`.

```
<Page loaded="onLoad">
<ListView items="{{ myArray }}">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="{{ UUID }}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thank you! As I was typing out my own answer I saw yours come in.